# how to load database url database name using .env file in codeigniter version 3.1.6

Tags: php, codeigniter, deployment, codeigniter-3

```
database.default.hostname = ''
database.default.database = ''
database.default.username = ''
database.default.password = ''
database.default.DBDriver = 'mysqli'
```

**I created a .env file like this and in database.php i call it like below**

```
$db['default'] = array(
  'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => env('database.default.hostname'),
    'username' => env('database.default.username'),
    'password' => env('database.default.password'),
    'database' => env('database.default.database'),
    'DBDriver' => env('database.default.DBDriver'),
];
```

**but it gives me internal server error, by hardcoding in database.php it works but i want to load it from .env file**

load data from .env file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first install this library by using this command

> composer require vlucas/phpdotenv

**set up environment file**

```
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Add following code line to the on top of the index.php

```
    $dotenv = \Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(FCPATH);
    $dotenv->safeLoad();
```

after that in the database.php change like below

```
    $host = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
    $username = $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'];
    $password = $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'];
```

**note that in codeigniter 4 has built-in support for env files no need install 3rd party libraries**